# Google app scripts - how to get cell alignments from range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How do you get the alignments of a range of cells in Google App Scripts?

I can see methods for getting colors, background etc, but nothing for alignments other than getAlignment

```
  var range = getFullRange();
  var colours = range.getFontColors(); // this works
  var alignments = range.getAlignment(); // this does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer:

`var alignments = range.getHorizontalAlignments();`